# Linking Images Mystery

Tags: image, hyperlink

I am working on a site that has a lot of images. I've gotten all of the images linked except for one. I have no idea why this one image won't link. If any one has any ideas, that would be a great help. Thanks!

Also, the image I am trying to link is named:timthumb.php.jpeg
And, here is a link to the site: http://emilymagnuson.com/bobsoutdoorgoods/Novelty1.html

Here's a snippet of the code where the image is linked:

```
 <div class="centerbox4" id="centerbox4">
    <div class="singleproductimage" id="singleproductimage"><img     src="../../../images/_ProductImages/Cycle/Novelty/Large400/timthumb.php.jpeg" width="400"    height="400" alt="REI HooDoo Tent" />
   </div>
    <div class="ProductDescription" id="ProductDescription">
      <p><span class="darkparagraph">ULock Belt</span><br />
        This ULock Belt is very handy for keeping your ULock in a safe place.</p>
      <p><br />
        <span class="largeprice">$55.00</span>
        <br /><br />
        Item # 748114
        <br />
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      </p>
      <p>
          <label for="menudrop"></label>


        <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<form action="http://www.mydomain.com/myformhandler.cgi" method="post" name="dropdown"     id="dropdown">
                    <div align="left">
                      <select name="mydropdown">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
        </form>
     <br />
     <a href="#"><img src="../../../images/addtocart.jpg"     onmouseover="../../images/addtocarthover.jpg" onmouseout="../../images/addtocart.jpg"     width="150" height="39" alt="Add To Cart" /></a>
   </div>
  </p>
            </div>
  </div>
<!--EndCenterBox2-->
</div>
<!--EndCenterBox-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is the URL for the broken image is actually not an image.  Just go to this URL in a browser:

http://emilymagnuson.com/bobsoutdoorgoods/images/_ProductImages/Cycle/Novelty/timthumb.php.jpeg

PHP spits out the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/content/e/m/i/emilymagnuson/html/bobsoutdoorgoods/images/_ProductImages/Cycle/Novelty/timthumb.php.jpeg
>   on line 57

And `timthumb.php` seems to be a PHP script.

Looking at the code in the site utself it seems like you have that link hardcoded for some reason:

```
<!--ProductBox-->     
    <div class="productbox" id="productbox">
    <!--ProductImage-->   
      <div class="productimage" id="productimage"><a href="IndividualProductPages/Cycle/Novelty/ULockBelt.html"><img src="images/_ProductImages/Cycle/Novelty/timthumb.php.jpeg" width="200" height="200" alt="ULock Belt" /></a>


      </div><!--EndProductImage-->

<!--ProductDescription-->        
        <div class="Productdescription" id="Productdescription"><span class="lightparagraph">ULock Belt</span><br />
          <span class="darkparagraph"> $55.00</span>          

          <!--EndProductDescription-->        
    </div>

    </div>
<!--EndProductBox-->
```

Seems like a simple image URL mistake on your part.

Comment: What is an image URL mistake?

Answer (score 1):

In general when diagnosing broken links like this, first confirm that the image is where you think it should be. Then confirm that the image itself is readable as an image and not corrupt by copying it to your workstation and trying to view it there. Then try linking to it directly in your browser. It is probably something simple that is wrong. The developer tools that come with Safari, Chrome, or as plug-ins for Firefox ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), for example) can help a lot, too.

Comment: Thank you all, it ended up that the image had two file types attached to it. It was the .php attached to the .jpeg. So I took the .php out and it worked. THank you!